# Why is my used range not counting the correct used Range?

Tags: excel

My code below works perfectly fine with **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016** it is selecting the last *used.row* which is **14th column**; however with **Microsoft 365** version it selects on **13th column**. Why is it not working properly?

```
Sub SelectLastUsedRange()

Dim Master As Workbook
Dim MasterLastColumn As Long

Set Master = ThisWorkbook

    MasterLastColumn = Master.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Master.Sheets(1).Activate
    Master.Sheets(1).Cells(2, MasterLastColumn).Select

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your A column is empty, so used range is from B to N, so 13 columns. Now when you use 13 to select from beginning it is in M column.

Comment: @user11222393, hmmm I see it makes sense, however I tried running the same macro on a different PC with Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 version, it selected on the 14th column even if A column is empty. Do you think that this is a version issue or something else?